# Can i invoke ASP.net page handler in console app?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httprequest

I want to get 20000 HttpRequest or Page.Request instances from console app in less than 10 min. Anyone knows how to do it?

I am able to get 20000 instances in a very inefficient way: 
in the first asp.net page using HTTPWebRequest to call the second asp.net page. Then get the Page.Request of the second page stored in Application object and retrieve it from the first page in the same web application but it takes about 30 mins for 20000 Page.Request.

I added Thread.Sleep(80) in the first page otherwise it will give "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted ".

I think it's too long. just wondering if there is any better way to do it.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Web Application Stress Tool

http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1298

Been a long time since I've used it, but I'm fairly certain you can invoke it and start a test from the command line.